# Using Git for development-to-deployment process

Tags: git, deployment

I am going to set up a development-to-deployment process for my team. I am using Git for version control.
I have a solution like this:

- Production: branch master, stable versions.
- Staging: branch staging, stable versions for QC testing.
- Development: each branch Dev- is for a feature.

I merge branches on staging and production as deployment.
But, I have two problems:

1. When error occurs after merging, "separate" branches is roll back to previous version on branch staging or master?
2. How to set permissions for my team-mates on branches?

If you have any better solution for this process, please give me advices!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Capistrano? Please check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano) Capistrano is an open source tool for running scripts on multiple servers; its main use is deploying web applications. It automates the process of making a new version of an application available on one or more web servers, including supporting tasks such as changing databases.

Answer (score 1):

1) This question is clearly explained in the [GIT manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). I highly suggest you read it especially in the branch section.

2) I suggest you setup a [gitolite (link)](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/) account on your server. Gitolite is a very simple-to-use plugin for GIT that allows you to fine-tune permissions in your projects.